# ZF2 model classes not found when moved to src\MyApp\Model\Repository

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm trying to move database table classes to the recommended location of \Model\Repository instead of \Model for better segmentation of model code. But when I do, it can't find the classes. I'm rather new to ZF2, so it's probably something simple. I'm assuming that it's possible to place model classes into segmented directories for better classification of model class files.

This works:

module\Client\src\Client\Model\ClientTable.php

Paths to ClientTable.php from Module.php:

```
    public function getServiceConfig() {
    return array(
        //  setup multiple table access by model as {tablename}Table
        'factories' => array(
            'Client\Model\ClientTable' => function($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $table = new Model\ClientTable($dbAdapter);
                return $table;
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

But trying to call from Repository breaks it and results in the class method not being found, but it should be found if it's within the Module directory, right?

module\Client\src\Client\Model\Repository\ClientTable.php

Paths to ClientTable.php from Module.php:

```
    public function getServiceConfig() {
    return array(
        //  setup multiple table access by model as {tablename}Table
        'factories' => array(
            'Client\Model\Repository\ClientTable' => function($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $table = new Model\Repository\ClientTable($dbAdapter);
                return $table;
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you didn't change the namespace of your model class when you moved it to the Repository folder. ie change `namespace Client\Model;` to `namespace Client\Model\Repository;` in your `ClientTable.php` file.

Comment: @Crisp - I tried adding namespace Client\Model\Repository as you suggested before posting the question with no joy. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an issue with the class autoload paths. You should go to your module config (module.config.php and  module.php) an update the namespaces mapping to point to the new location of the files.

for example, you will have a function like this in module.php

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig() {
    return array (
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array (),
             'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array (
                    'namespaces' => array (
                            __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                                "DBAL\\Entity" => __DIR__ . '/src/DBAL/Entity',
                            "DBAL\\Entity\\User" => __DIR__ . '/src/DBAL/Entity/User' 
                    ) 
            ) 
    )
    ;
}
```

Thats a piece of code of one of my projects. If you post your `module.config.php` and your `module.php` i can give you more specific help

probably you had some mappings pointing to `src\MyApp\Model` and you have to change them to `src\MyApp\Model\Repository`

Also, be sure that you have the correct  `Client\Model\Repository` namespaces in your moved files

Comment: Note on solution: I didn't need to change anything with my AutoloaderConfig(). I changed the namespace on the Model/Repository classes to include Repository, changed the paths referencing them to include Repository in Module.php::getServiceConfig() and anywhere else the class methods are called. Still learning this stuff, thanks! :)

Comment: great!! all this is so confusing at the beginning but soon you get used to it and it is easy to find this kind of things.